# Using USB-C Headphones with an iPhone via a Lightning to USB-C cable doesn't work

Tags: iphone, headphones, lightning

I have the [beyerdynamic MMX 150](https://north-america.beyerdynamic.com/mmx-150.html) headphones which are wired headphones. They feature an USB-C port. There is an option to use them with a **USB-C to 3.5mm** cable and also to use an **USB-C to USB-A** cable to use the onboard sound card of the headphones on the computer.

For listening on my Macbook and iPad Pro I swapped the **USB-C to USB-A** cable to an **USB-C to USB-C** cable without problems.

Since my iPhone 8 only has a Lightning connector, I'm using the **Lightning to 3.5mm** dongle from Apple with the **USB-C to 3.5mm** cable. This is basically a Lightning to USB-C connection made from two parts so I got the idea to use a **Lightning to USB-C** cable instead. Now I got the named cable but it doesn't seem to work. I checked if the cable is okay and it does transfer data from my Macbook to my iPhone but the headphones simply don't work. I also tested this with an iPhone 6 and an older iPad Pro without any luck.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: When you go to 3.5 mm you loose the digital signal data. I don’t think the headphone usb-c input has a analog-digital converter which would require some power coming from nowhere. You should try to fin a lightning to USB-c converter.

Comment: Agree. But where is the difference in using an USB-C to USB-C cable with an USB-C to lightning adapter to using an USB-C to lightning cable in the first place?

Comment: I disagree with the choice to close this question since this appears to be a different situation.  It appears this headset uses the new USB-C analog audio standard to connect to devices, as well as USB.  This headphone is not using only USB to connect and so the answer will differ from that for the other question.  There's not enough room here to explain how this works and the options to resolve the issue.

Comment: The real question is: why does an lightning to usb c connection via the 3.5mm dongle work but a plain lightning to usb c cable doesnt. The only reason i can think of is that the 3.5mm dongle uses different pins in the lighting port than the lightning to usb c cable

Comment: “ The only reason i can think of is that the 3.5mm dongle uses different pins in the lighting port than the lightning to usb c cable”  It uses the same pins but uses them differently. USB-C and Lightning support USB host mode, USB guest mode, audio mode, and other modes note exactly relevant to this question.  The USB-C cable puts the Lightning port into USB guest mode and the headphone USB-C port on the headset supports only USB guest mode and audio mode.  I’d have more room to explain further if the question was not erroneously marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Since this does not appear to be getting unlocked I’ll answer in a series of comments.  It appears this headset is using the USB-C Audio Adapter Accessory mode for analog audio input and output.  Some info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Audio_Adapter_Accessory_Mode  Using the USB-C to 1/8” jack cable is then using a DAC in the Lightning adapter for analog audio.  The Lightning to USB-C cable is built to handle USB and power, not analog audio.  The USB-C end is to be plugged into a computer or power brick, not headphones.

Comment: Plug a standard USB-C to USB-A cable into the headset and the headset enters USB guest mode, as opposed to the analog audio mode, which then has the connections for power and USB to drive a DAC in the headset for sound.  By using a Lightning to USB Camera adapter the headphones should work as intended, using the DAC in the headset for analog audio.  The camera adapter name is a misnomer because it allows for connections to a wide variety of devices, including USB audio adapters like that in the headset. https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter

Comment: Put a Lightning to USB adapter with a USB cable to the headset and the headset goes into USB guest mode, the iPhone goes into USB host mode and then audio happens.  Put a Lightning to 1/8” headphone jack adapter with an analog audio 1/8” plug to USB-C and the headset goes into analog audio mode then audio happens.  A Lightning to USB-C cable that handles analog audio would need a DAC inside, and putting a DAC inside would be more complex and quite likely violate the USB-C specification.  With two ways to wire the cable they have to pick one or make the cable more complex and more expensive.